# Showing this fraction is less than one?

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, fractions, ratio

And also, what are some techniques to show such a thing. That is, what are standard techniques for showing a fraction is less than one? I'm just trying to refresh/improve/add to my toolbox.

The fraction I am working with is:
$$
\frac{tx(tx+1) +t^2}{(tx+1)^2}
$$
The problem is: Show
$$
\frac{tx(tx+1) +t^2}{(tx+1)^2} \leq 1 \text{ for } x \geq t,\ t\geq 0
$$

I have been trying to move the denominator to the right and show that the numerator is less than the denominator, but I am not seeing any clean cancellations, or obvious result.

Comment: What if $x =0, t = -2$?

Comment: $t\geq 0$. Sorry, I didn't think consider that before typing. I will edit my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x\ge t\ge0$, we have $tx\ne-1$ and so
$$\eqalign{t^2\le tx\quad
  &\Rightarrow\quad t^2\le tx+1\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad tx(tx+1)+t^2\le tx(tx+1)+tx+1\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad tx(tx+1)+t^2\le (tx+1)^2\ .\cr}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the help.